# How to forward mail classified as spam by spamassassin to dspam?

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, dspam

i'm using postfix, amavis-new, clamav and spamassassin.

Now I'm thinking of having dspam together, and training dspam from data collected by spamassassin. Any possible way to forward mail classified as spam by spamassassin to dspam either
directly from spamassassin or from amavis-new?

TQVM.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script that crawl the users "Spam" folder and train dspam from those mails.

You could also filter mail from amavisd-new with something like:

(blow is just an example stub config, untested)

/etc/postfix/dspam_filter_access

```
/^<xxx-spam-regex-subject?,to?>.*$/ FILTER dspam:dspam
/./ OK
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
dspam                 unix    -       n       n       -       -    pipe \
flags=Ru user=dspam argv=/usr/bin/dspam --client --deliver=innocent,spam --user \
${recipient} --mail-from=${sender}
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
check_client_access pcre:/etc/postfix/dspam_filter_access
dspam_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

At startup, modern `amavisd-new` version look for a number of binaries in `$PATH`, including the `dspam` executable. If this one is found, dspam will automatically be trained with the results of all other spam checks configured in amavisd-new.

The only downside is: All mail content is learned with only one user id (same as amavisd-new's SA integration).

And, totally OT: dspam is simply not worth the hassle.